# Legend on plot3d of rgl package

Tags: r, legend

I am new to R. So please bear with me even if this questions seems a little silly to you.

I want to draw a legend on a rgl plot, depicting the meaning of colours (ie what numbers do the colored spheres on the plot correspond to). Here is my code for constructing it:

```
plot3d(t$x,t$y,t$z,col=colors,type = 's', size=4,
       xlim=8, ylim=8, zlim=8, image=TRUE, legend=TRUE, lty=1, cex=0.5)
```

I have searched everywhere on the internet, but I can`t find how to place a legend on 'RGL' plot. Everywhere it says about how to put a legend on graphs drawn using 'plot; function of graphics package.
Also, I have also tried this (apart from above code):

```
plot3d(t$x,t$y,t$z,col=colors,type = 's', size=4,xlim=8,ylim=8,zlim=8)
legend(100,100,c("Zero",
                 "Between 1 and 10","Between 10 and 25",
                 "Between 25 and 50","Between 50 and 70",
                 "More than 70","Other"),
         lty=c(l,l,l,l,l,l,l), lwd=c(2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5),
         col=c("White", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Magenta"))
```

And I get the following output:
`Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet`

Please help me how to do it.. Thank you in advance..

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rgl` package, however there is a good reason why your 2nd attempt fails with the error message indicated. You are "mixing" multiple graphics APIs.  R has 3 main graphics libraries: base graphics (plot and the like), lattice and ggplot2, not to mention other, special purpose libraries like rgl for example.  Although these libraries sometimes share a few components, they are generally based on very different principles and do not inter-operate.  `legend()`, for e.g. belongs to the base graphics and is only applicable to annotate an existing plot [created by base graphics]

Comment: ... and that explains the message: Base graphics is saying "I cannot annotate anything since a new plot (created by plot.new) has yet to be created".   Now, I'm unsure if `rgl` uses a similar system, whereby one first creates a plot and then annotates its (with legends, titles, extra lines etc.), as opposed to requiring that all the annotations be introduced with the plot creation call.  Maybe you can check the documentation with this particular insight in mind (figure out if annotations are created with the initial plot or added thereafter, then find the relevant API calls and/or options)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a legend to rgl plots using `legend3d()`.

Comment: @Jeeped: As far as I can see, it exactly answers the question. The author mixed up base graphics and rgl, but is actually only missing the correct command.